# Python module imageop deprecated: but it's useful in CGI to create thumbnails! How else?

Tags: python, cgi, thumbnails, scale

Python's imageop module is quite useful in CGI to create thumbnails from uploaded images automatically, but according to its [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/imageop.html), it's deprecated since 2.6.

I'm working on a shared server, so I can not install PIL, imagemagick or something similar by myself. How else could I create a thumbnail from an uploaded image? Because Javascript can't do that on the client side, not without using canvas, right?

Comment: If you shared hoster doesn't even have PIL available and doesn't give you a way to install additional python packages, consider changing the hoster. The same applies if you have to use classic CGI - it's extremely slow compared to FCGI or WSGI.

Comment: Sometimes you just can't choose. It's a contract job and the client already has her hosting solution. I have to adapt to that situation and use CGI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that you can't do that with javascript - not without passing back the whole image content back to the browser.

As for Python - being "deprecated" dos not mean it is removed - it is still around in Python 2.7, and since Python 2.7 will be maintained more or less "forever", as everyone will take some more several years to move to Python 3.x, you can count on imageop being available.

As for installing PIL - which is "the way to go" - you don't have to install it as root - it can be instaled as a unix user. Which means: you need shell access, or at least file deployment access, isntall it on a directory you have write access, and set PYTHONPATH accordingly.

However, it can be tricky to install PIL this way, it can be done - in the worst case (if you have only file write access, but no shell), you'd have to mimic the running environment on your side (for example, having a VM installed with the same library versions that are on your server), and build it there, and then move the files to the server.

Searching for a  pure Python way of dealing with images yields [PNGCanvas](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/projects/PNGCanvas), but it does not have image scaling capabilities. (and can only deal with PNG files, of course).

Another alternative is to make use of a web service to perform image operations for you - yu'd then post the whole image to an app in another server, and retrieve only your thumbnail. Searching for "free image webservice" yields a number of results.

Comment: Know what? I finally created a php script that I invoke with my Python script to create the thumbnail :( But you are right about imagop, I'll try that.

Comment: False, I finally used imagemagick, as it was available in the server :D